# How to give RANKs based on employee hierarchy in emp table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have emp table and KING is the CEO of the company, he does not have a manager.
KING should get RANK '1'. 
KING is the manager for JONES,CLARK,BLAKE. So these will get RANK '2'....etc.

intermediate table for emp and manager relation:

```
empno   ename   mgr
7566    JONES   KING
7782    CLARK   KING
7698    BLAKE   KING
7900    JAMES   BLAKE
7844    TURNER  BLAKE
7654    MARTIN  BLAKE
7521    WARD    BLAKE
7499    ALLEN   BLAKE
7934    MILLER  CLARK
7902    FORD    JONES
7788    SCOTT   JONES
7876    ADAMS   SCOTT
7369    SMITH   FORD
7839    KING    NULL
```

Final output should be like:

```
mgr   rank    
KING    1
JONES   2
CLARK   2
BLAKE   2
JAMES   3
TURNER  3
MARTIN  3
WARD    3
ALLEN   3
MILLER  3
SCOTT   3
FORD    3
ADAMS   4
SMITH   4
```

Thanks in advance. I want this to be done in oracle.

Comment: Search Oracle docs for `CONNECT BY` clause and pseudo-column called `LEVEL`

Comment: You've listed two different RDBMS  which one is this really for or does it have to be database agnostic?  the SQL syntax will vary by engine.

Comment: in case of MySQL there is no way. connect by is Oracle's proprietary extension and recursice CTEs (SQL standard) are not supported either.

Comment: Using user variables and temp tables, I believe there may be a way to do this in mySQL. but not in a single statement.

Comment: @xQbert I tagged msql to get any logic other than specific commands related to engine. As i mentioned in question, I prefer answer in oracle only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me while to wrap my head around the heirarchy queries in the past ... however, once you take the time to fiddle with them, they usually aren't that tough.

```
  SQL> with w_data as (
    2           select 7566 empno, rtrim('JONES ') ename, rtrim('KING ') mgr from dual union all
    3           select 7782 empno, rtrim('CLARK ') ename, rtrim('KING ') mgr from dual union all
    4           select 7698 empno, rtrim('BLAKE ') ename, rtrim('KING ') mgr from dual union all
    5           select 7900 empno, rtrim('JAMES ') ename, rtrim('BLAKE') mgr from dual union all
    6           select 7844 empno, rtrim('TURNER') ename, rtrim('BLAKE') mgr from dual union all
    7           select 7654 empno, rtrim('MARTIN') ename, rtrim('BLAKE') mgr from dual union all
    8           select 7521 empno, rtrim('WARD  ') ename, rtrim('BLAKE') mgr from dual union all
    9           select 7499 empno, rtrim('ALLEN ') ename, rtrim('BLAKE') mgr from dual union all
   10           select 7934 empno, rtrim('MILLER') ename, rtrim('CLARK') mgr from dual union all
   11           select 7902 empno, rtrim('FORD  ') ename, rtrim('JONES') mgr from dual union all
   12           select 7788 empno, rtrim('SCOTT ') ename, rtrim('JONES') mgr from dual union all
   13           select 7876 empno, rtrim('ADAMS ') ename, rtrim('SCOTT') mgr from dual union all
   14           select 7369 empno, rtrim('SMITH ') ename, rtrim('FORD ') mgr from dual union all
   15           select 7839 empno, rtrim('KING  ') ename, NULL           mgr from dual
   16           )
   17  select empno, ename, mgr, level
   18    from w_data
   19   connect by mgr = PRIOR ename
   20   start with mgr IS NULL
  /
   21
       EMPNO ENAME  MGR        LEVEL
  ---------- ------ ----- ----------
        7839 KING                  1
        7698 BLAKE  KING           2
        7499 ALLEN  BLAKE          3
        7900 JAMES  BLAKE          3
        7654 MARTIN BLAKE          3
        7844 TURNER BLAKE          3
        7521 WARD   BLAKE          3
        7782 CLARK  KING           2
        7934 MILLER CLARK          3
        7566 JONES  KING           2
        7902 FORD   JONES          3

       EMPNO ENAME  MGR        LEVEL
  ---------- ------ ----- ----------
        7369 SMITH  FORD           4
        7788 SCOTT  JONES          3
        7876 ADAMS  SCOTT          4

  14 rows selected.

  SQL>
```

- w_data is just to fake out your test data ..
- connect by mgr = prior ename
  this takes each record, and compares the mgr with the previous level employee.
- start with mgr is null
  this tells Oracle where to start ...
- Level is the depth of the heirarchy.

Comment: Thanks..Today I learned new clauses CONNECT BY, START WITH. I wonder how we can achieve hierarchical queries without this CONNECT BY clause.

Comment: I got the final query with your inputs. Query is:

`SELECT empno, ename, mgr,LEVEL FROM emp CONNECT BY PRIOR empno = mgr START WITH mgr is null`

Comment: use of Recursive Common Table Expressions would work as well but mySQL doesn't support them.  Oracle does in newer versions.

Comment: @Naveen: I believe it can also be done with "recursive subquery factoring", however, I'm still trying to wrap my head around that one as well O.o  (basically, it's a WITH clause that self references itself ... )

Answer (score -2):

I believe Oracle supports `CASE WHERE` in the `ORDER BY` clause. Something like this:

```
SELECT [blah]
FROM [intermediate tbl]
ORDER BY
    CASE WHEN mgr IS NULL THEN 1
    CASE WHEN mgr = 'KING' THEN 2
    ... ELSE ... END
```

I believe there is a shorter way to do this in Oracle (my experience is with SSMS):

```
ORDER BY decode(mgr, 'NULL', 1, 'KING', 2, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply. This is a generic one, I got the answer using CONNECT BY clause.